# jQuery array for bootstrap modals

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is that when I click the button View more info, the modal opens and shows a picture of the worker and some info but my problem is that I have over 30 rows of workers and I want it show each respectively. I know this is because of the id tag that is unique and each row is using it. I found a similar question here but I cannot comment since I'm a new member. 
A guy said about

```
$("[id^='myModal']")
```

How do I apply it? I tried putting it directly inside my script tag w/ ; but it didn't worked. I have little knowledge in both javascript and jquery and I'm still learning.

Here's my html/php code below by the way. It works but it shows the same information/output on all rows because of the shared id tag. Both your help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
  ................................
  echo "<td><button class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' 
  data-target='#myModal'>View more info</button></td>";
  echo "
     <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
     <div class='modal-dialog modal-vertical-centered'>
     <div class='modal-content'>
     <div class='modal-header'>
      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
      <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      Lorem Ipsum <img src='../data/worker_pics/".$row[10]."'>
      echo "<td>".$row[11]."</td>";
      ..........
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>";
}
```

Comment: what is your question???

Comment: All rows has the same info because of the id tag. Worker#1 and Worker#2 and all. I want to show their own info respectively. How can I do it?

Comment: Never mind sir. Thank you for your time. I got it. I just put $count = 0 outside while() then increment it inside and viola id='myModal".$count."' . I'm so happy I've been stuck for a day w/ this.